# Change Tile Size of Mapbox Tiles using React Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, mapbox, react-leaflet

Is it possible to change the tile size of Mapbox tiles when using `react-leaflet`?

The rendered tiles has text that look too tiny, which makes me think that these are 512px tiles being treated by Leaflet as 256px tiles. I am experiencing this on an external monitor connected to a Macbook Pro (with Retina screen). Not sure if the retina screen affects anything.

Looked into the [`react-leaflet` docs for `TileLayer`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components#tilelayer) but it does not expose the `tileSize` parameter. [Mapbox's tile URL template](https://docs.mapbox.com/archive/ios/maps/api/4.0.2/tile-url-templates.html) also doe not accept a parameter for defining the tile sizes.

Is there another way to adjust the tile size? Thank you!

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from 'react-leaflet';

export function MapView({markers, center}) {
    return (
        <MapContainer center={[center.at, center.lon]}>
            <TileLayer 
                url={`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=${config.mapbox}`}
            />
                { markers.map((marker, index) => (
                    <Marker position={[marker.lat, marker.lon]} key={index} />
                ))}
        </MapContainer>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own TileLayer component and define the `tileSize` with           `zoomOffset`

```
 function TileLayer() {
    const map = useMap();

    useEffect(() => {
      new L.TileLayer(
        `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=${yourToken}`,
        {
          tileSize: 512,
          zoomOffset: -1
        }
      ).addTo(map);
    }, []);

    return null;
  }
```

and use it as a regular MapContainer's child.

Here is a similar thread in [vanilla leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346360/how-do-i-increase-the-font-size-of-contents-in-map-in-leaflet-js)

Comment: Works thanks! Does having a non-Retina screen cause any problems after you set tileSize and zoomOffset like in the solution? No non-Retina machine right now for me to check this out.

Comment: Note to self: `react-leaflet`'s `TileLayer` does accept `tileSize` and `zoomOffset` but were not included in the docs.

Comment: Its usually safe to assume that any react-leaflet component inherits all options from its associated vanilla leaflet component...I find myself with the leaflet docs open more often than react-leaflet docs, even when working on RL projects

Comment: @Nyxynyx "zoomOffset: -1" doesn't work right in the current react-leaflet (v3.2.1). Instead of actually subtracting it from {z}, it concatenates it into a string like "10-1", and the Mapbox API throws an error

Comment: @RodBoev Hi, only change `zoomOffset="-1"` by `zoomOffset={-1}`